# Show Next button then when reaching bottom show Previous button and change at the top again

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout, scrollto

Scenario: I have a sequence of  float: none; divs, which require the user to scroll down in order to see them. I have made some controls using Prev (up) and Next (down). So basically clicking Next will scroll the first div to the top of the page, click it again and the next div scrolls up. This all works fine (FYI: Using [ScrollTo Plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)) but I can't for the life of me get the controls to do the following:

Question: At the top show the Next (down) button until you reach the bottom of page then fadeOut and fadeIn the Prev (Up) button, once your back at the top, fadeOut Prev (Up) button and fadeIn the Next (Down) button:

This is what I have, which almost works but there's some craziness going on.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $(".next").fadeOut(100, function() {
            $(".prev").fadeIn(100);
        });

    } else {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                    $(".next").fadeOut(100, function() {
                        $(".prev").fadeIn(100);
                        });
                        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have actually almost done this but still need help. I had the last FadeIn / Out in the wrong order. Now, once I get to bottom. The Next (Down) changes to a Prev (Up).. but once back at the top the Prev (Up) button just stays as is. I know this is because of the else statement but I can figure out the best way to write this. Help, anyone? (Code above has been changed accordingly)